# Why is read_line(..) much slower than lines()?

Tags: io, rust

The code below runs much slower when calling `read_line(..)` than `lines()`
You can't run it in the playground but for me this prints the following

```
lines()     took Duration { secs: 0, nanos: 41660031 }
read_line() took Duration { secs: 2, nanos: 379397138 }
```

The [implementation of `Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#1960) does pretty much what I wrote (but more!) why is there such a difference?

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};
use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:80")
        .expect("listen failed");
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                for x in 1..1000 + 1 {
                    stream.write_all(format!("{}\n", x).as_bytes())
                        .expect("write failed");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    let start_a = std::time::Instant::now();
    {
        let stream_a = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:80")
            .expect("connect_a failed");
        let br = BufReader::new(stream_a);
        for l in br.lines() {
            println!("{}", l.unwrap());
        }
    }
    let end_a = std::time::Instant::now();

    let start_b = std::time::Instant::now();
    {
        let stream_b = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:80")
            .expect("connect_b failed");
        let mut br = BufReader::new(stream_b);
        let mut s = String::with_capacity(10);
        while br.read_line(&mut s).unwrap_or(0) > 0 {
            println!("{}", s);
        }
    }
    let end_b = std::time::Instant::now();

    let dur_a = end_a - start_a;
    let dur_b = end_b - start_b;

    println!("lines()     took {:?}", dur_a);
    println!("read_line() took {:?}", dur_b);

}
```

[same code on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=04d0b1b99c9260f9cbcec6c6edac0d0a&version=nightly)

Comment: **Did you test using the `--release` flag**? That's the #1 issue whenever someone says that Rust code isn't "fast enough".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's take a look at the output of your program:

```
1 
2 
...
999
1000
1

1
2

1
2
3

1
2
3
4

1
2
3
4
5

...
```

Ooops. It's just a simple bug in your code: you never `clear()` the string. Each `read_line()` call appends to your string. When I add a `s.clear()` in your `while` loop, the timings are more comparable:

```
lines()     took Duration { secs: 0, nanos: 7323617 }
read_line() took Duration { secs: 0, nanos: 2877078 }
```

In your buggy program, most of the time was probably wasted reallocating the string and printing it to the terminal.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot

Comment: 15 years of programming, and this caught me too. Feels like this mistake should be a lot harder to make in Rust than it currently is.