# Weird behaviour when using read_line in a loop

Tags: rust

My first program in Rust is supposed to take input from the user in the form of characters, either C or F:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut srcunit = String::new();

    let mut switch = true;
    while switch {
        println!("source unit? F or C?");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut srcunit).expect(
            "failed to read src unit",
        );

        if srcunit.trim() == "F" || srcunit.trim() == "C" {
            println!("doing things right with {}", srcunit);
            switch = false;
        } else {
            println!("either F or C, not {}", srcunit);
        }
    }

    println!("you pressed {}", srcunit);
}
```

When I start the program and press either F or C, it works right, so I'm skipping this here. The weird part comes when I press another character. I expect my program to ask again for either F or C until I press one of those characters. When I do, it should leave the while loop and tell me what I've pressed.

```
source unit? F or C?
G
either F or C, not G //so far so good

source unit? F or C?
F
either F or C, not G //why is F not assigned to the srcunit variable? It's supposed to leave the loop now.
F                    //why does it print this line? I didn't press a key or have a println function/macro that does this

source unit? F or C?
V
either F or C, not G //it's still G, wtf
F                    //again, why are those two lines printed? Where does it store, that I pressed F previously?
V
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [documentation for `read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> Read all bytes until a newline (the 0xA byte) is reached, and **append** them to the provided buffer.

(Emphasis mine.)  You need to clear the string before reading the next line, for example by calling the [`clear()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear) method on the string, otherwise the answers are accumulated in the variable.

Alternatively, you can define the variable in the loop (but this is slightly less efficient because this way, `String` will not be able to reuse the already allocated storage for the next answer, it has to be deallocated and reallocated again).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220448/why-is-read-line-much-slower-than-lines), asked recently.  Looks like this is a common trap.

Comment: In other words, those extra lines are printed because they're part of `srcunit`. `read_line` keeps adding the new data to the end of it.

Comment: The key example in [that example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#allowing-multiple-guesses-with-looping) (hope I got the link right) is that the variable is declared in the loop, so it is automatically recreated for each iteration.